# How to pick up and use varying number of users in a group and get them to do some task in Jmeter

Tags: regex, loops, jmeter

Wonder if any one could help!

I m trying replicate scenario where a group could have varying number of members. All these members has a file attached to them as well. I need to pickup these users and associated file and them to a batch task. Currently, Im having to fix the number of users to 15 do this but keen to do this with varying number users. I have used regEx extractor to pick these 2 values and using it in following HTTP request. In the image attached, the 'ReportUids' and the 'ContributerUids' are the one in question. How do I get Jmeter to pick up these if there are dynamic??

[Bactch Script Step 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpKbE.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Beanshell PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PreProcessor) for dynamically adding request parameters.

1. Add Beanshell PreProcessor as a child of your `Batch Step 3 of 5` request
2. Put the following code into Beanshell PreProcessor's "Script" area

   ```
   Iterator it = vars.getIterator();
   while (it.hasNext()) {
       Map.Entry var = (Map.Entry) it.next();
       log.info("Processing variable: " + var.getKey());
       if (var.getKey().toString().startsWith("Pld")) {
           sampler.addArgument("ContributorUids", var.getValue().toString());
       }
       if (var.getKey().toString().startsWith("Ruid")) {
           sampler.addArgument("ReportUids", var.getValue().toString());
       }

   }
   ```

See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for extended information on using Beanshell in JMeter.

The tricky thing is that uniqueness of HTTP method parameter names isn't a must so it's up to a developer how to handle duplicate parameter names. JMeter uses Java [Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) to store arguments so it will be the most recent one. If you need to amend arguments names as well - you should be able to do it by slightly changing above Beanshell.

Comment: Thanks for that Dmitri! Is there a way to do the same without any codes, i mean with the default Jmeter config elements, controllers etc. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I'm not aware of other ways of doing it. For POST request it  could be a pre-defined large array of variables, those which are not initialised won't appear in the request body, but it won't play for GET requests.